# array and if statment of $_POST array is wrong

Tags: php

How do i iterate over the $departments array and test to see if it equals the $name variable value and return "checked" if its in the list. departments is an array of checkboxes

```
function isChecked($name) {
$departments = (isset($_POST["interests"])) ? $_POST["interests"] : array();
foreach ($departments as $key => $value) {
    // this next line here is wrong 
    if($departments[$key][$value] == $name) { 
        return "checked";   
    };      
}
return "";
```

}

Comment: What does your form look like? Is it the key or the value you are testing?

Comment: related to your last question. This code won't work. I think the code of the last question was correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're referring to the `$value` wrong inside the foreach loop. `$value` contains just what it says, the value of what is inside the `$departments` array.

```
function isChecked($name) {
$departments = (isset($_POST["interests"])) ? $_POST["interests"] : array();
foreach ($departments as $key => $value) {
    if($value == $name) { 
        return "checked";   
    };  
}
return "";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

instead of if($departments[$key][$value] == $name)

use

```
if($value == $name)
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use either

```
if ($departments[$key] == $name) { ... }
```

or

```
if ($value == $name) { ... }
```

`$department[$key]` gives you the value at `$key` in the `$department` array, but that value is also helpfully stored in `$value` since you set it up in the loop definition.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
function isChecked($name) {
    return isset($_POST['interests'][$name]);
}
```

If you *need* the function to return the string value `checked` if true, you can do this.

```
return isset($_POST['interests'][$name]) ? 'checked' : '';
```